# How to setup language fallbacks properly in TYPO3 9.5.7?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

I'm working on a TYPO3 9.5.7 website with many languages. So far I get proper fallbacks for the pagetitles/menu but not for the content. No TypoScript is used for the configuration, as far as I understand TYPO3 v9 all is handled by the "Site Manager". The website uses some "generic" languages like en,de,fr,it and some "sublanguages" like en-us,de-ch,fr-be which should use the proper fallback to their generic language.

I did some digging in about the problem but so far I only found some bugtracker tickets which should be resolved and fixed in TYPO3 9.5.7.
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86762

Here is the language part of my config.yaml:

```
languages:
  -
    title: English
    enabled: true
    languageId: '0'
    base: /en/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: 'International (en)'
    hreflang: en
    direction: ltr
    flag: en-us-gb
  -
    title: 'en-AU | english (Australia)'
    enabled: true
    languageId: '1'
    base: /en-au/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_AU.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: 'Australia (en)'
    hreflang: en-AU
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '0'
    flag: en-us-gb
  -
    title: 'en-CA | english (Canada)'
    enabled: true
    languageId: '2'
    base: /en-ca/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_CA.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: 'Canada (en)'
    hreflang: en-CA
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '0'
    flag: en-us-gb
  -
    title: 'en-GB | english (United Kingdom)'
    enabled: true
    languageId: '3'
    base: /en-gb/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_GB.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: 'United Kingdom (en)'
    hreflang: en-GB
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '0'
    flag: en-us-gb
  -
    title: 'en-NZ | english (New Zealand)'
    enabled: true
    languageId: '4'
    base: /en-nz/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_NZ.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: 'New Zealand (en)'
    hreflang: en-NZ
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '0'
    flag: en-us-gb
  -
    title: 'en-US | english (USA)'
    enabled: true
    languageId: '5'
    base: /en-us/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_US.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: 'USA (en)'
    hreflang: en-US
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '0'
    flag: en-us-gb
  -
    title: 'en-ZA | english (South Africa)'
    enabled: true
    languageId: '6'
    base: /en-za/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_ZA.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: 'South Africa (en)'
    hreflang: en-ZA
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '0'
    flag: en-us-gb
  -
    title: 'de | german (generic)'
    enabled: true
    languageId: '7'
    base: /de/
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: 'Deutschland (de)'
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: free
    flag: de
  -
    title: 'de-AT | german (Austria)'
    enabled: true
    languageId: '8'
    base: /de-at/
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_AT.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: 'Österreich (de)'
    hreflang: de-AT
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '7'
    flag: de
  -
    title: 'de-CH| german (Switzerland)'
    enabled: true
    languageId: '9'
    base: /de-ch/
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_CH.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: 'Schweiz (de)'
    hreflang: de-CH
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '7'
    flag: de
  -
    title: 'fr | french (generic)'
    enabled: true
    languageId: '10'
    base: /fr/
    typo3Language: fr
    locale: fr_FR.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: fr
    navigationTitle: 'France (fr)'
    hreflang: fr
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: free
    flag: fr
  -
    title: 'fr-CA | french (Canada)'
    enabled: true
    languageId: '11'
    base: /fr-ca/
    typo3Language: fr
    locale: fr_CA.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: fr
    navigationTitle: 'Canada (fr)'
    hreflang: fr-CA
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '10'
    flag: fr
  -
    title: 'fr-CH | french (Switzerland)'
    enabled: true
    languageId: '12'
    base: /fr-ch/
    typo3Language: fr
    locale: fr_CH.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: fr
    navigationTitle: 'Suisse (fr)'
    hreflang: fr-CH
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '10'
    flag: fr
  -
    title: 'fr-BE | french (Belgium)'
    enabled: true
    languageId: '13'
    base: /fr-be/
    typo3Language: fr
    locale: fr_BE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: fr
    navigationTitle: 'Belgique (fr)'
    hreflang: fr-BE
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '10'
    flag: fr
  -
    title: 'it | italian (generic)'
    enabled: true
    languageId: '16'
    base: /it/
    typo3Language: it
    locale: it_IT.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: it
    navigationTitle: 'Italia (it)'
    hreflang: it
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: free
    flag: it
```

The fallbacks work properly for the english sublanguages en-au,en-gb,... but not for the other sublanguages like de-at,fr-be,...

I only get the site (no 404) with the proper translated page title but no content elements.

To render the content in my fluid templates I use this viewhelper `<v:content.render column="0"></v:content.render>`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the "vhs" Extension. Of course this extension would need to support content fallback as well.

However, I also believe that multi-level content fallback hasn't been implemented yet in TYPO3 v9 (it wasn't implemented in previous versions either natively).